# combining ks.test, var.test, t.test and wilcox.test into a decision-tree like function or if else function in r

Tags: r, if-statement, decision-tree

I have my data like:

```
df1 <- read.table(text = "A1 A2 A3 A4 B1 B2 B3 B4
1 2 4 12 33 17 77 69
34 20 59 21 90 20 43 44
11 16 23 24 19 12 55 98
29 111 335 34 61 88 110 320
51 58 45 39 55 87 55 89", stringsAsFactors = FALSE, header = TRUE, row.names=c("N1","N2","N3","N4","N5"))
```

I want to compare the values between `A` and `B`, by row. First I want to test whether the distribution of `A` and `B` is normal distributed by `ks.test`. Second I will test whether the variation between `A` and `B` is different by `var.test`. For non-normal distributed results (p ks.test <0.05), I will conduct the wilcox test by `wilcox.test`. For normal distributed results, I will conduct the ttest by separating them into equal and unequal variance ttest by `t.test`. Finally I combine all the results.

What I have done is, first, I set up five functions of `ks.test`, `var.test`, `wilcox.test` and two `t.test`:

```
kstest<-function(df, grp1, grp2) {
  x = df[grp1]
  y = df[grp2]
  x = as.numeric(x)
  y = as.numeric(y)  
  results = ks.test(x,y,alternative = c("two.sided"))
  results$p.value
}
vartest<-function(df, grp1, grp2) {
  x = df[grp1]
  y = df[grp2]
  x = as.numeric(x)
  y = as.numeric(y)  
  results = var.test(x,y,alternative = c("two.sided"))
  results$p.value
}
wilcox<-function(df, grp1, grp2) {
  x = df[grp1]
  y = df[grp2]
  x = as.numeric(x)
  y = as.numeric(y)  
  results = wilcox.test(x,y,alternative = c("two.sided"))
  results$p.value
}
ttest_equal<-function(df, grp1, grp2) {
  x = df[grp1]
  y = df[grp2]
  x = as.numeric(x)
  y = as.numeric(y)  
  results = t.test(x,y,alternative = c("two.sided"),var.equal = TRUE)
  results$p.value
}

ttest_unequal<-function(df, grp1, grp2) {
  x = df[grp1]
  y = df[grp2]
  x = as.numeric(x)
  y = as.numeric(y)  
  results = t.test(x,y,alternative = c("two.sided"),var.equal = FALSE)
  results$p.value
}
```

Then I calculated the p value of `ks.test` and `var.test` for subsetting the data:

```
ks_AB<-apply(df1,1,kstest,grp1=grepl("^A",colnames(df1)),grp2=grepl("^B",colnames(df1)))

ks_AB
[1] 0.02857143 0.69937420 0.77142857 0.77142857 0.21055163

var_AB<-apply(df1,1,vartest,grp1=grepl("^A",colnames(df1)),grp2=grepl("^B",colnames(df1)))

var_AB
[1] 0.01700168 0.45132827 0.01224175 0.76109048 0.19561742

df1$ks_AB<-ks_AB
df1$var_AB<-var_AB
```

Then I subset the data by what I have described above:

```
df_wilcox<-df1[df1$ks_AB<0.05,]
df_ttest_equal<-df1[df1$ks_AB>=0.05 & df1$var_AB>=0.05,]
df_ttest_unequal<-df1[df1$ks_AB>=0.05 & df1$var_AB<0.05,]
```

Finally I calculate the corresponding test to the new dataframes, and merge the results

```
wilcox_AB<-as.matrix(apply(df_wilcox,1,wilcox,grp1=grepl("^A",colnames(df_wilcox)),grp2=grepl("^B",colnames(df_wilcox))))

ttest_equal_AB<-as.matrix(apply(df_ttest_equal,1,ttest_equal,grp1=grepl("^A",colnames(df_ttest_equal)),grp2=grepl("^B",colnames(df_ttest_equal))))

ttest_unequal_AB<-as.matrix(apply(df_ttest_unequal,1,ttest_unequal,grp1=grepl("^A",colnames(df_ttest_unequal)),grp2=grepl("^B",colnames(df_ttest_unequal))))

p_value<-rbind(wilcox_AB,ttest_equal_AB,ttest_unequal_AB)
colnames(p_value)<-c("pvalue")

df<-merge(df1,p_value,by="row.names")

df
  Row.names A1  A2  A3 A4 B1 B2  B3  B4      ks_AB     var_AB     pvalue
1        N1  1   2   4 12 33 17  77  69 0.02857143 0.01700168 0.02857143
2        N2 34  20  59 21 90 20  43  44 0.69937420 0.45132827 0.39648631
3        N3 11  16  23 24 19 12  55  98 0.77142857 0.01224175 0.25822839
4        N4 29 111 335 34 61 88 110 320 0.77142857 0.76109048 0.85703939
5        N5 51  58  45 39 55 87  55  89 0.21055163 0.19561742 0.06610608
```

I know my code is tedious and stupid, but it works for my data very well. I am now want to know I do I combine my above code to a new decision-tree-like function of if else function, which will like:
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should do the trick:

```
FOO <- function(df, grp1, grp2){

  # perform rowwise kolmogorov smirnov test
  ks_AB <- apply(df, 1, kstest, grp1 = grp1, grp2 = grp2)

  # subset data by significance of ks test
  sub1 <- df[ks_AB < .05, ]
  sub2 <- df[ks_AB >= .05, ]

  if(nrow(sub1) > 0){
    # perform wilcoxon rank sum test on non-normally distributed data
    wilc_AB <- apply(sub1, 1, wilcox, grp1 = grp1, grp2 = grp2)
  }

  if(nrow(sub2) > 0){
    # perform f test on normally distributed data
    var_AB <- apply(sub2, 1, vartest, grp1 = grp1, grp2 = grp2)

    # subset data by significance of f test
    varsub1 <- sub2[var_AB < .05, ]
    varsub2 <- sub2[var_AB >= .05, ]

    if(nrow(varsub1) > 0){
      # perform t test with unequal variance on subset with unequal variance
      t_uneq_AB <- apply(varsub1, 1, ttest_unequal, grp1 = grp1, grp2 = grp2)
    }

    if(nrow(varsub2) > 0){
      # perform t test with equal variance on subset with equal variance
      t_eq_AB <- apply(varsub2, 1, ttest_equal, grp1 = grp1, grp2 = grp2)
    }
  }

  # put together output dataframe
  df$ks_AB <- ks_AB

  if(exists("var_AB")){
    df$var_AB <- NA
    df$var_AB[row.names(df) %in% names(var_AB)] <- var_AB
  }

  df$pvalue <- NA

  if(exists("wilc_AB")){
    df$pvalue[row.names(df) %in% names(wilc_AB)] <- wilc_AB
  }

  if(exists("t_uneq_AB")){
    df$pvalue[row.names(df) %in% names(t_uneq_AB)] <- t_uneq_AB
  }

  if(exists("t_eq_AB")){
    df$pvalue[row.names(df) %in% names(t_eq_AB)] <- t_eq_AB
  }

  # return output
  return(df)
}
```

Applied on your data example:

```
> FOO(df1, grepl("^A",colnames(df1)), grp2=grepl("^B",colnames(df1)))
   A1  A2  A3 A4 B1 B2  B3  B4      ks_AB     var_AB     pvalue
N1  1   2   4 12 33 17  77  69 0.02857143         NA 0.02857143
N2 34  20  59 21 90 20  43  44 0.69937420 0.45132827 0.39648631
N3 11  16  23 24 19 12  55  98 0.77142857 0.01224175 0.25822839
N4 29 111 335 34 61 88 110 320 0.77142857 0.76109048 0.85703939
N5 51  58  45 39 55 87  55  89 0.21055163 0.19561742 0.06610608
Warning messages:
1: In ks.test(x, y, alternative = c("two.sided")) :
  cannot compute exact p-value with ties
2: In ks.test(x, y, alternative = c("two.sided")) :
  cannot compute exact p-value with ties
```

You could suppress those warnings with `suppressWarnings()` within the function, but I'd rather have them displayed so you know when tests may not be exact.

Comment: Thank @LAP so much for the reply. May I know it is possible to combine several if statement like you post together? I am new to R so I am not very familiar with if else function. What you post is very useful for me but what I expect is a more simple code statement

Comment: The `ifelse()` function is typically used for vectorized conditional output and not really useful in your case. You could probably simplify my function by cutting out exceptions, but that would leave you with a function that does not work on fringe cases.